# select all rows when its values smaller than specify number?

Tags: mysql

i have a table :

```
a       b       c
1       10     1001
7       6      54
56     2000    31
1200    5      9
4       10     20
2       65     20
```

how can i select rows with column's value of this row smaller than 1000. i want to get this

```
a       b       c
7       6      54
4       10     20
2       65     20
```

mysql query still get all value :

```
SELECT a,b,c FROM test
    where a <'1000' or b<'1000' or c<'1000'
```

Comment: Try with `and` instead of `or`

Comment: Replace the `Or` by `AND` like this: `SELECT a,b,c FROM test where a < '1000' AND b < '1000' AND c < '1000'`

Comment: can you check it by removing single quote, pls. Because used data type is mismatches with the other. a,b, & c might be int and you compaired it as string.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you would like to pull a row where there is NO column greater than 1000 in that row, if that is correct then you need to us AND instead of OR.

```
SELECT a,b,c FROM test
where a <'1000' AND b<'1000' AND c<'1000'
```

Hope that helps!